# convert csv to netcdf

Tags: python, csv, netcdf

I am trying to convert a .csv file to a netCDF4 via Python but I am having trouble figuring out how I can store information from a .csv table format into a netCDF.  My main concern is how do we declare the variables from the columns into a workable netCDF4 format?  Everything I have found is normally extracting information from a netCDF4 to a .csv or ASCII.  I have provided the sample data, sample code, and my errors for declaring the appropriate arrays.  Any help would be much appreciated.

The sample table is below:

```
Station Name    Country  Code   Lat Lon mn.yr   temp1   temp2   temp3   hpa 
Somewhere   US  12340   35.52   23.358  1.19    -8.3    -13.1   -5  69.5
Somewhere   US  12340           2.1971  -10.7   -13.9   -7.9    27.9
Somewhere   US  12340           3.1971  -8.4    -13 -4.3    90.8
```

My sample code is:

**#!/usr/bin/env python**

```
import scipy
import numpy
import netCDF4
import csv

from numpy import arange, dtype
```

**#Declare empty arrays**

```
v1 = []
v2 = []
v3 = []
v4 = []
```

**# Open csv file and declare variable for arrays for each heading**

```
f = open('station_data.csv', 'r').readlines()

for line in f[1:]:
    fields = line.split(',')
    v1.append(fields[0]) #station
    v2.append(fields[1])#country
    v3.append(int(fields[2]))#code
    v4.append(float(fields[3]))#lat
    v5.append(float(fields[3]))#lon
#more variables included but this is just an abridged list
print v1
print v2
print v3
print v4
```

**#convert to netcdf4 framework that works as a netcdf**

```
ncout = netCDF4.Dataset('station_data.nc','w')
```

**# latitudes and longitudes. Include NaN for missing numbers**

```
lats_out = -25.0 + 5.0*arange(v4,dtype='float32')
lons_out = -125.0 + 5.0*arange(v5,dtype='float32')
```

**# output data.**

```
press_out = 900. + arange(v4*v5,dtype='float32') # 1d array
press_out.shape = (v4,v5) # reshape to 2d array
temp_out = 9. + 0.25*arange(v4*v5,dtype='float32') # 1d array
temp_out.shape = (v4,v5) # reshape to 2d array
```

**# create the lat and lon dimensions.**

```
ncout.createDimension('latitude',v4)
ncout.createDimension('longitude',v5)
```

**# Define the coordinate variables. They will hold the coordinate information**

```
lats = ncout.createVariable('latitude',dtype('float32').char,('latitude',))
lons = ncout.createVariable('longitude',dtype('float32').char,('longitude',))
```

**# Assign units attributes to coordinate var data. This attaches a text attribute to each of the coordinate variables, containing the units.**

```
lats.units = 'degrees_north'
lons.units = 'degrees_east'
```

**# write data to coordinate vars.**

```
lats[:] = lats_out
lons[:] = lons_out
```

**# create the pressure and temperature variables**

```
press = ncout.createVariable('pressure',dtype('float32').char,('latitude','longitude'))
temp = ncout.createVariable('temperature',dtype('float32').char,'latitude','longitude'))
```

**# set the units attribute.**

```
press.units =  'hPa'
temp.units = 'celsius'
```

**# write data to variables.**

```
press[:] = press_out
temp[:] = temp_out

ncout.close()
f.close()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "station_data.py", line 33, in <module>
    v4.append(float(fields[3]))#lat
ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Comment: The error says that value in `fields[3]` is not a number, hence it cannot be converted to float. Check your input file for this value.
You can also try printing the value of `fields[3]` before converting it to float and adding to list `v4`

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying that. You are correct, by just printing it it worked but I wasn't confident that it would transfer well when going into a netcdf. These are latitudes so by assigning them any data type, is that okay when transferring over to netcdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see your input file, there is no value corresponding to column **Lat** in second row.
When you read the csv file this value i.e. `fields[3]` is stored as an empty string `""`. That's why you are getting a `ValueError`. 
Instead of using the default function you can define a new function which can handle this error:

```
def str_to_float(str):
    try:
        number = float(str)
    except ValueError:
        number = 0.0
# you can assign an appropriate value instead of 0.0 which suits your requirement
    return number
```

Now you can use this function in place of built-in float function this way:

```
v4.append(str_to_float(fields[3]))
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int) SO question which gives more insight into string to int or float conversion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough explanation. I didn't realize it was storing this as an empty string.  This new method makes sense and works fantastic.

Comment: Would it be possible to inquire about possible solutions for part 2 of this problem?  Are there any resources that can provide a clearer explanation of how to import the declared variables from the above .csv file into a netCDF4 file? There doesn't seem to be a great deal of information of the conversion from .csv to netcdf. I have been replacing the press_out, temp_out, lats, and lons with the v (1,2,3...etc) variables but it is not registering the information I am trying to transfer into a netcdf4 format. Would you be able to provide any additional assistance?

Comment: I am sorry. I am not familiar with netCDF4. I think you should treat this problem as 2 sub problems: 1. Read data from csv, store it in variables.(You have already done it) 2. Use this data stored in variables to feed them to netCDF variables. I think you should check the [documentation](http://unidata.github.io/netcdf4-python/netCDF4-module.html) for the second part. In case you get any errors while doing so, post the errors so that cause of that error can be identified.

Answer (score 12):

This is a perfect job for [xarray](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/), a python package that has a dataset object representing the netcdf common data model.  Here's an example you can try:

```
import pandas as pd
import xarray as xr

url = 'http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/precip/CWlink/'

ao_file = url + 'daily_ao_index/monthly.ao.index.b50.current.ascii'
nao_file = url + 'pna/norm.nao.monthly.b5001.current.ascii'

kw = dict(sep='\s*', parse_dates={'dates': [0, 1]},
          header=None, index_col=0, squeeze=True, engine='python')

# read into Pandas Series
s1 = pd.read_csv(ao_file, **kw)
s2 = pd.read_csv(nao_file, **kw)

s1.name='AO'
s2.name='NAO'

# concatenate two Pandas Series into a Pandas DataFrame
df=pd.concat([s1, s2], axis=1)

# create xarray Dataset from Pandas DataFrame
xds = xr.Dataset.from_dataframe(df)

# add variable attribute metadata
xds['AO'].attrs={'units':'1', 'long_name':'Arctic Oscillation'}
xds['NAO'].attrs={'units':'1', 'long_name':'North Atlantic Oscillation'}

# add global attribute metadata
xds.attrs={'Conventions':'CF-1.0', 'title':'AO and NAO', 'summary':'Arctic and North Atlantic Oscillation Indices'}

# save to netCDF
xds.to_netcdf('/usgs/data2/notebook/data/ao_and_nao.nc')
```

Then running `ncdump -h ao_and_nao.nc` produces:

```
netcdf ao_and_nao {
dimensions:
        dates = 782 ;
variables:
        double dates(dates) ;
                dates:units = "days since 1950-01-06 00:00:00" ;
                dates:calendar = "proleptic_gregorian" ;
        double NAO(dates) ;
                NAO:units = "1" ;
                NAO:long_name = "North Atlantic Oscillation" ;
        double AO(dates) ;
                AO:units = "1" ;
                AO:long_name = "Arctic Oscillation" ;

// global attributes:
                :title = "AO and NAO" ;
                :summary = "Arctic and North Atlantic Oscillation Indices" ;
                :Conventions = "CF-1.0" ;
```

Note that you can install `xarray` using `pip`, but if you are using the Anaconda Python Distribution, you can install it from the Anaconda.org/conda-forge channel by using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge xarray
```

Comment: pandas.errors.ParserError: Expected 21 fields in line 10, saw 22. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Answer (score 5):

While `xarray` mentioned above is a great tool, it is also worth looking at the UK Met Office's [`iris`](https://scitools.org.uk/iris/docs/latest/) library. A key advantage of Iris is that helps to create netCDF files that follow the Climate Forecast (CF-conventions). It does this by providing helper functions to define [standard names](http://cfconventions.org/standard-names.html), units, coordinate systems, and other metadata conventions. It also provides plotting, subsetting, and analysis utilities.

For earth science data such as this, CF is the [recommended standard for netCDF files](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/conventions.html)

As an example of its use, [this Python notebook](https://ocefpaf.github.io/python4oceanographers/blog/2014/08/04/time_series_cube/) re-implements the AO/NAO example above.

Comment: `iris` can be tough to install, but if you are using Anaconda, you can install it using `conda install -c conda-forge iris` by virtue of the Anaconda.org/conda-forge channel