# Convert time series data from csv to netCDF python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, netcdf, netcdf4

Main problem during this process is the code below:

```
precip[:] = orig
```

Produces an error of:

```
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 5732784 into shape (39811,144,144)
```

I have two CSV files, one of the CSV file contains all the actual data of a variable (precipitation), with each column as a station, and their corresponding coordinates is in the second separate CSV file. 
My sample data is in [google drive here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1VSOKp_xPLaSxOuDrtnI1VUriUyURETHV?usp=sharing).

If you want to have a look at the data itself, but my 1st CSV file has the shape (39811, 144) and 2nd CSV file has the shape (171, 10) but note; I'm only using the sliced dataframe as (144, 2).

This is the code:

```
stations = pd.read_csv(stn_precip)
stncoords = stations.iloc[:,[0,1]][:144]
orig = pd.read_csv(orig_precip, skiprows = 1, names = stations['Code'][:144])

lons = stncoords['X']
lats = stncoords['Y']

ncout = netCDF4.Dataset('Precip_1910-2018_homomod.nc', 'w')

ncout.createDimension('longitude',lons.shape[0])
ncout.createDimension('latitude',lats.shape[0])
ncout.createDimension('precip',orig.shape[1])
ncout.createDimension('time',orig.shape[0])

lons_out = lons.tolist()
lats_out = lats.tolist()
time_out = orig.index.tolist()

lats = ncout.createVariable('latitude',np.dtype('float32').char,('latitude',))
lons = ncout.createVariable('longitude',np.dtype('float32').char,('longitude',))
time = ncout.createVariable('time',np.dtype('float32').char,('time',))
precip = ncout.createVariable('precip',np.dtype('float32').char,('time', 'longitude','latitude'))

lats[:] = lats_out
lons[:] = lons_out
time[:] = time_out
precip[:] = orig
ncout.close()
```

I'm mostly basing my code to this post: [convert-csv-to-netcdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22933855/convert-csv-to-netcdf)
but does not include the variable 'TIME' as a 3rd dimension, so that's where I'm failing. 
I think I should be expecting the precipitation variable to have a shape in the form (39811, 144, 144), but the error suggests otherwise.

Not exactly sure how to deal with this, any inputs are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have data from different stations, I would suggest using dimension `station` for your netCDF file and not separate `lon` and `lat`. Of course, you can save the longitude and latitude of each station to separate variable.

Here is one possible solution, using your code as an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ipython
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import netCDF4

stn_precip='Precip_1910-2018_stations.csv'
orig_precip='Precip_1910-2018_origvals.csv'
stations = pd.read_csv(stn_precip)
stncoords = stations.iloc[:,[0,1]][:144]
orig = pd.read_csv(orig_precip, skiprows = 1, names = stations['Code'][:144])

lons = stncoords['X']
lats = stncoords['Y']
nstations = np.size(lons)

ncout = netCDF4.Dataset('Precip_1910-2018_homomod.nc', 'w')

ncout.createDimension('station',nstations)
ncout.createDimension('time',orig.shape[0])

lons_out = lons.tolist()
lats_out = lats.tolist()
time_out = orig.index.tolist()

lats = ncout.createVariable('latitude',np.dtype('float32').char,('station',))
lons = ncout.createVariable('longitude',np.dtype('float32').char,('station',))
time = ncout.createVariable('time',np.dtype('float32').char,('time',))
precip = ncout.createVariable('precip',np.dtype('float32').char,('time', 'station'))

lats[:] = lats_out
lons[:] = lons_out
time[:] = time_out
precip[:] = orig
ncout.close()
```

So the information about output file (`ncdump -h Precip_1910-2018_homomod.nc`) is like this:
[image]